# Newest version of plexus ftpd project

Tags: maven-2, maven, plexus

Can anyone provide the link to the svn repository latest version/tag of of Plexus FTP Server project? I only see version 1.0-alpha-1 at the [Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|ftpd) which is released in 2005.

Is it the current latest version? Isn't there a stable release at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look into the pom of that project there is the location of the SVN repository...

Comment: I did try that. It's https://svn.codehaus.org/plexus/trunk/plexus-servers/plexus-ftpd which is non-existent now. 
Little more digging brought me to https://svn.codehaus.org/plexus/tags/plexus-ftp-1.0-alpha-1. But that repository location did not get updated with recent releases as I understood. How do I know? Other listed projects at that location are older versions!